# Cors blocking ajax request, despite Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iis, cors

iam have a web app(written in php/codeigniter with some jquery) and iam trying to get data from AspNet web service via Ajax request.

JQuery code that handles request looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: webServiceURL,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml", 
            data: soapMessage,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: (response)=>{
                    //process response
                });
            }, 
            error: (error)=>{
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

Problem is, that its getting blocked by CORS. I mess around with it a little bit and now i get this error(before i wasnt sending correct origin header, now i send *):

> OPTIONS http://10.208.1.27/planws/Service.asmx 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.208.1.27/planws/Service.asmx' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Iam getting this error even that i configure IIS on server to respond with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" header. What else should i do to make it work?

response headers looks like this in Chrome developer tools/network:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

When i run chrome with disabled web security, it runs just fine.

Comment: You should add an Header into your backend code.

Comment: read this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-cors-in-asp-net-webapi-2/

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina no, that won't help; it's a *response* header, not a request header. OP should use the browser "Network" tab to see what headers are being returned; from the error it looks like you configured the server incorrectly.

Comment: @sarvon ks- this doesnt help, iam not using web api, iam using web service, and that works a little differently

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to switch you web service response from xml to json and use Jsonp.

```
$.ajax({
    url: webServiceURL,
    data: myData,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          },
});
```

Comment: Iam using Asp Net web Service, so iam stucked with Soap and xml.

Comment: @SkilledT  you can try this [solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/827596/Cross-domain-SOAP-call-with-XmlHttpRequest-to-a-we)

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party extension for chrome, if you are getting this error only for your local setup.

`Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` extension.

It is not a proper way but you can use it.

Comment: I need to solve this in my app or at the backend. My app will be accessible for users on the network, so solving this only on one station doesnt do the trick